# Как получить все значения таблицы, отсортировав по количеству записей в связанной таблице через спецификации?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteriabuilder

Есть две таблицы, эмейлы и рассылки. Связанные один ко многим. В представлении джавы у эмейла есть поле Collection<Рассылки>. Через Specification мне нужно получить все эмейлы у которых количество рассылок не больше какого то числа, которое приходит в метод. То есть мне нужно сначала посчитать сколько рассылок у каждого эмейла, сравнить, а после вывести нужные.

```
private static Specification<Email> isCountSendLessThan(Long count){
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(criteriaBuilder.count(root.get("mailing")),count);
    }
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, но у меня не выходит

Comment: Через Specification такое трудновато сделать но можно. Может воспользуетесь [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) как более подходящий вариант для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Subquery<Long> sq = query.subquery(Long.class);
            Root<Email> sqr = sq.from(Email.class);
            Predicate sqIdEq = criteriaBuilder.equal(sqr.get("id"), root.get("id"));
            Join<Object, Object> mailingRoot = sqr.join("mailing");
            sq.select(criteriaBuilder.count(mailingRoot)).where(sqIdEq);
            return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(sq, count);
        };
```